# whitespace problem magento admin html grid renderer

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I have rewritten the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`
with `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`
& have created a renderer to display customer's email column in grid.

Here is my renderer file:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Renderer_Customer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract 
{

public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{   
    $model = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($row->getCustomerId());

    return  $model->getEmail();

 }

}
```

& here is my Grid changes (I just added a column, & I intend to make it search-able)

```
$this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));
       // this is new col.
    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'renderer' => 'adminhtml/renderer_customer',

    ));
```

I am getting what I want. But this col/  has a lot of whitespace both leading & trailing
due to this I think this col. is not search-able.
Can Anybody suggest what can be done in order to remove these white spaces

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT**
After few days I have figured out that these white spaces are common in the grid & it has nothing to do with the search-able option.
Can anybody suggest that how to make a custom column in search-able that has been added to a grid by using a renderer ???
Thanks

**2 EDIT**
Guys According to the **clockworkgeek** I have customized
my `_prepareCollection()` method of the overwritten grid as follows

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
  { 
    // 'sales/order_collection' is changed from 'sales/order_grid_collection'
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');  

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'order_address/firstname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'order_address/lastname', 'shipping_address_id', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_fax', 'order_address/fax', 'billing_address_id', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'order_address/telephone', 'billing_address_id', null, '')

    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('billing_name',
    'CONCAT({{billing_firstname}}, " ", {{billing_lastname}})',
    array('billing_firstname', 'billing_lastname'))


    ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('shipping_name',
    'CONCAT({{shipping_firstname}}, " ", {{shipping_lastname}})',
    array('shipping_firstname', 'shipping_lastname'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I also have investigated that for Grid Magento obtains data from **sales_flat_order_grid** table not from **sales_flat_order** this is the reason it was reporting error of unknow column as per the  **clockworkgeek** first solution

THe issue with current implementation is Magento reports an error  **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection::addExpressionAttributeToSelect()**

as Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection does not have addExpressionAttributeToSelect method instead it has **addExpressionFieldToSelect** method
Now I need help to write a proper syntax for addExpressionAttributeToSelect method. Changing the method name only is not helping me. I also have referred the docs

Answer (score 0):

Add `'index'     => 'email'` to your `addColumn()` in the Grid.php and then try something like this:

```
$emailaddress = trim($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
return '<a href="mailto:'.$emailaddress.'">'.$emailaddress.'</a>';
```

That way you strip the whitespace and also provide a clickable link for your admin users :)

Comment: first of all `trim($row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()))` is null I Logged it & find it out.
Second, if I add any html tag the whitespaces are gone. But its not searchable anymore. My basic requirement is it must be searchable like other cols. Moreover `'index' => 'email'` reports an error `Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'` Thanks anyway. At least I know how to add send mail option if my requirement team ask me to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to the second part of your question may I offer this little trick.

Adminhtml grid columns can take an extra `filter_condition_callback` parameter which takes a standard [PHP callback type](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). In your case you might modify the grid like this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    // ...
    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'renderer' => 'adminhtml/renderer_customer',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'addCustomerEmailFilter'),
    ));
}

public function addCustomerEmailFilter(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $collection, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $column->getFilter()->getValue());
}
```

But all that still feels a bit messy, especially if the attribute is not a first class column. For those unusual cases you can combine the output processing and searching in the collection class...

```
protected function _initSelect() {
    parent::_initSelect();

    // email is existing column, customer_email is generated column
    $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
        'customer_email',
        'TRIM({{email}})',
        array('email')
    );

    return $this;
}
```

The [`addExpressionAttributeToSelect()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.html#addExpressionAttributeToSelect) method temporarily stores the SQL expression as a mapped field so that when a grid tries to search for `customer_email` it gets substituted by the expression instead.

Comment: thanks I did the first step. I had an error `Unknown column 'customer_email' in 'where clause'`. which is obvious as order collection never have an attribute `customer_email` it only has `customer_id`. Moreover I looked the **Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Grid_Collection** class there is no such function `_initSelect()`. Please forgive me I don't have much knowledge of Collections & customizing them. But there is only constructor there. Thanks

Comment: can I do that in `_prepareCollection() `  of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class that I have overwritten?

Comment: You can use `addExpressionAttributeToSelect()` when preparing collection. I think if you did that there wouldn't be a need for a custom filter so you can ignore the first half of my answer.

Comment: where I should add this method in `_prepareCollection()` of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class or somewhere else. I have rewritten the grid class but not model or collection. Thanks for the support

Comment: Yes, modify the `_prepareCollection()` function which I believe already has some uses of `addExpressionAttributeToSelect()`.